# Merge two dataframes on string column - compound string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two huge dataframes (**4+ millions each**) that have the following structure:

Dataframe A:

```
     date    Fruit        a    b    c    d
     01      "apple"      0    3    5    1
     03      "apple"      8    2    7    2
     02      "banana"     1    4    3    5
     04      "banana"     3    5    2    6
     03      "pineapple"  2    6    4    6
     05      "pineapple"  3    5    7    9
```

Dataframe B:

```
     date   Fruits                         x    y    z 
     01     "apple, pear, strawberry"      a    n    q 
     02     "banana, apple, coconut"       b    m    p 
     03     "pineapple, pear, banana"      c    s    o
     04     "banana, apple, coconut"       d    f    v 
     05     "pineapple, pear, banana"      r    ñ    t
```

What I am trying to achieve is a third dataframe with the following structure:

Dataframe C:

```
     date   Fruit        a    b    c    d    x    y    z
     01     "apple"      0    3    5    1    a    n    q
     03     "apple"      0    3    5    1    0    0    0
     02     "banana"     1    4    3    5    b    m    p
     04     "banana"     1    4    3    5    d    f    v
     03     "pineapple"  2    6    4    6    c    s    o
     05     "pineapple"  2    6    4    6    r    ñ    t
      ...
```

I had already tried something like:

```
test = market_test.assetCode.apply(lambda x : news_test.assetCodes.str.find(x)>=0)
```

But my kernel breaks, I also had tried using a for cycle to expand the  fruit column of **B** dataframe into a 'fruit-b' column, keeping the data from the other **B** columns and then merging between the date column and the '**fruit-B**' columns, but the time of execution is too high.

Is there a way of obtaining dataframe **C** using dataframe **A** and **B** that does not consume a lot of time and memory?

**Fruit** and **Fruits** columns type is string.

Comment: What is the total number of unique fruits occurring across df_A and df_B? You could convert them to one-hot or Categorical, instead of storing as string.

Comment: `df_B.Fruits` is a ***compound column***. I would retitle this *"Merge two dataframes on string column/ compound string column"*

Comment: @smci, thanks for your response, the unique fruits number should be around 5000, i'll rename the question as you suggested too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df_A)

   date      Fruit  a  b  c  d
0     1      apple  0  3  5  1
1     3      apple  8  2  7  2
2     2     banana  1  4  3  5
3     4     banana  3  5  2  6
4     3  pineapple  2  6  4  6
5     5  pineapple  3  5  7  9

print (df_B)

   date                   Fruits  x  y  z
0     1  apple, pear, strawberry  a  n  q
1     2   banana, apple, coconut  b  m  p
2     3  pineapple, pear, banana  c  s  o
3     4   banana, apple, coconut  d  f  v
4     5  pineapple, pear, banana  r  ñ  t
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Split the strings into list.
df_B.Fruits = df_B.Fruits.str.split(', ')

# reindex and repeat on length of list
temp = df_B.reindex(df_B.index.repeat(df_B.Fruits.str.len())).drop('Fruits',1)

temp['Fruit'] = np.concatenate(df_B.Fruits.values)

df_C = df_A.merge(temp, on=['date','Fruit'], how='left').fillna(0)

print (df_C)

   date      Fruit  a  b  c  d  x  y  z
0     1      apple  0  3  5  1  a  n  q
1     3      apple  8  2  7  2  0  0  0
2     2     banana  1  4  3  5  b  m  p
3     4     banana  3  5  2  6  d  f  v
4     3  pineapple  2  6  4  6  c  s  o
5     5  pineapple  3  5  7  9  r  ñ  t
```